# How to integrate OPENID auth into a REST api and front-end framework architecture

Tags: openid, frontend, jwt, steam

I am currently making a site that requires a user to log in with [Steam](http://steamcommunity.com/) before they can use the rest of my website's functionality. Steam currently only supports OPENID for authentication. The way that I have done it is in these following steps:

1. User presses on "Log in with Steam" button
2. My front-end redirects to steamcommunity.com
3. If the user logged in successsfully, the user's browser should redirect to my backend, I then add the user to the database (if they are not in it already) and create a JSON web token and send it back to my front end.

   for example:

   `myfrontend.com?token={my_json_web_token}`
4. My front end then saves this token as a client side cookie and on every request to the server, I will send the contents of this cookie to the server.

I have already integrated my app but it is just gaining popularity so I'm wondering if the way that I have implemented it works.

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your example for how the backend communicates the token to the front end? Also on what your stack is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like the correct way to go about it.

One thing to note is that you want to make sure you have some CSRF protection since you are using cookies, but that wasn't exactly what you were asking.

[CSRF example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Example_and_characteristics)

Comment: How could hackers do a cross site request forgery though? They would have to guess my jwt password do to something like that wouldn't they?

Comment: @mre12345 a very good explanation is [here](https://www.hacksplaining.com/exercises/csrf) (signup is painless sso). Essentially if you put your token in a cookie, and the browser sends the cookie to your server automatically on every request: then attackers pages can make authorized requests to your site because the browser will send the cookie for them.